# Unable to run an application in iPad (Swift iOS)

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, swift3

I have developed one application in Swift 3 it will be run successfully in simulator and iPhone 6s device but it was unable to run in iPad.

Following error will be displayed:

---

> dyld: Library not loaded:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Messages.framework/Messages   Referenced
>   from:
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F457076E-DC6C-480B-A9C6-2007014BE246/FlexiCalc.app/FlexiCalc
>   Reason: image not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

link your libraries in General -> Embedded Binaries section and remove old one